# How to display quick horizontal menu

Tags: launcher, menu

I'd like to know how to display this quick horizontal menu in ubuntu 16.04

[image]

Comment: alt + tab? or super + tab?

Comment: alt + tab show that menu but it disappears quickly

Comment: press and hold alt and keep pressing tab repeatedly to switch between applications

Comment: Is it possible to keep the menu opened even when stop pressing alt ?

Comment: @DavidFoerster : https://askubuntu.com/questions/967629/keep-switch-application-menu-opened