# Keep switch applications menu opened

Tags: application-switcher

I'm using ubuntu 16.04 , I press alt + tab to show the menu of switch applications. Is it possible to keep this menu opened even when stop pressing alt ?

[image]

up

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the behaviors of the **Application Switcher** using **Compiz Manager**.

Install it with:

```
sudo apt-get install compizconfig-settings-manager 
sudo apt-get install compiz-plugins
```

Then, open *compizconfig-settings-manager* with *alt-F2* and typing *ccsm*.

Scroll down to *Ubuntu Unity Plugin* and choose the tab *Switcher*.